# Variable visibility

Tags: java, caching, concurrency

I have legacy code that has cache implementation that looks like this:

```
long lastUpadate;
...

public void checkCach(){

     if(lastUpdated + UPDATE_INTERVAL < System.currentTimeMillis()){
          synchronized(this){
               //cache update goes here
               lastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
          }
     }
}
```

Can there be a problem in multicore processor enviroment that Threads would not see updated lastUpdate field because they check it outside of synchronized section (issue of processors core caches)?

Updated: also can reordering be applied to this synchronized block, that first lastUpdate field would be set and only then cache update would be executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `lastUpdate` is a field variable set it to `volatile lastUpdate` to force all threads trying to view its value to cross the memory barrier. Therefore you can guaranteed that whatever thread is reading `lastUpdate`, they will get the most recent value. Beware though, volatile cannot guarantee *atomic* operations.

Answer (score 1):

> Can there be a problem in multicore processor enviroment that Threads
>   would not see updated lastUpdate field because they check it outside
>   of synchronized section (issue of processors core caches)?

Yes. *Reads and writes* on shared data must be synchronized to ensure visibility in multithreaded environments.